# How can I change the size of a checkbox in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I made some checkboxes with PySimpleGUI like so:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

WINDOW_SIZE = (1280, 710)
CHECKBOX_SIZE = (1000, 40)

sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')

indicator_column = [
    [sg.Checkbox("First", size=CHECKBOX_SIZE)],
    [sg.Checkbox("Second")],
    # in the actual code there are more checkboxes
]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(indicator_column)]
]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True, size=WINDOW_SIZE)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

window.close()
```

I want to adjust the size of the checkbox by using its `size` property, but this seems to have no effect. Why doesn't the first checkbox have a custom size when set as in the above code? How can I change the size?

Comment: You can't with the current checkbox implementation.  The best thing to do is make your own checkboxes using Text elements and Unicode chars with the events enabled.  There may be demo programs that show it.  The toggle-button demo is a similar implementation.  It's a tkinter limitation.

Comment: @MikefromPSG that's worth an answer - the fact that something can't really be done, doesn't invalidate a "how-to" question, as long as it's reasonable to expect a way *a priori* and there aren't any other issues. I cleaned up the wording a bit.

Comment: OK, added an answer, but Jason, as always, has a better solution than I do  so not sure how much it'll help LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find one solution posted on [Trinket](https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/custom-elements-buttons-radio-buttons-etc/custom-checkboxes) where you can execute it.  It's based on a PySimpleGUI Demo Program, also posted in the PSG Repo and in the psgdemos PyPI release.

Like the normal Checkbox Element, you can click the box or the text next to it. This bit of code also flips the text, something not normally done so you can remove that line of code if desired.

Another way is to use Text Elements instead of Image Elements, swapping Base64 images with UNICODE chars.

To get the value of a checkbox 1:

```py
window[window[('-IMAGE-', 1)].metadata
```

Or you can add to your event loop right after your read:

```py
values['-CB 1-'] = window[('-IMAGE-', 1)].metadata
values['-CB 2-'] = window[('-IMAGE-', 2)].metadata
```

Like this

```py
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        values['-CB 1-'] = window[('-IMAGE-', 1)].metadata
        values['-CB 2-'] = window[('-IMAGE-', 2)].metadata
```

and then reference the checkboxes using the values dictionary just as if they were PySimpleGUI Checkbox Elements:

```py
if values['-CB 1-']:
    # your checkbox is true
```

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Demo - Custom Checkboxes done simply

    The Base64 Image encoding feature of PySimpleGUI makes it possible to create beautiful GUIs very simply

    These 2 checkboxes required 3 extra lines of code than a normal checkbox.  
    1. Keep track of the current value using the Image Element's Metadata
    2. Change / Update the image when clicked
    3. The Base64 image definition

    Enable the event on the Image with the checkbox so that you can take action (flip the value)
"""


def main():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Fancy Checkboxes... Simply')],
              [sg.Image(checked, key=('-IMAGE-', 1), metadata=True, enable_events=True), sg.Text(True, enable_events=True, k=('-TEXT-', 1))],
              [sg.Image(unchecked, key=('-IMAGE-', 2), metadata=False, enable_events=True), sg.Text(False, enable_events=True, k=('-TEXT-', 2))],
              [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    window = sg.Window('Custom Checkboxes', layout, font="_ 14")
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        # if a checkbox is clicked, flip the vale and the image
        if event[0] in ('-IMAGE-', '-TEXT-'):
            cbox_key = ('-IMAGE-', event[1])
            window[cbox_key].metadata = not window[cbox_key].metadata
            window[cbox_key].update(checked if window[cbox_key].metadata else unchecked)
            # Update the string next to the checkbox (optional)
            window[('-TEXT-', event[1])].update(window[cbox_key].metadata)

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    checked = b'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'
    unchecked = b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAKMGlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAeJydlndUVNcWh8+9d3qhzTAUKUPvvQ0gvTep0kRhmBlgKAMOMzSxIaICEUVEBBVBgiIGjIYisSKKhYBgwR6QIKDEYBRRUXkzslZ05eW9l5ffH2d9a5+99z1n733WugCQvP25vHRYCoA0noAf4uVKj4yKpmP7AQzwAAPMAGCyMjMCQj3DgEg+Hm70TJET+CIIgDd3xCsAN428g+h08P9JmpXBF4jSBInYgs3JZIm4UMSp2YIMsX1GxNT4FDHDKDHzRQcUsbyYExfZ8LPPIjuLmZ3GY4tYfOYMdhpbzD0i3pol5IgY8RdxURaXky3iWyLWTBWmcUX8VhybxmFmAoAiie0CDitJxKYiJvHDQtxEvBQAHCnxK47/igWcHIH4Um7pGbl8bmKSgK7L0qOb2doy6N6c7FSOQGAUxGSlMPlsult6WgaTlwvA4p0/S0ZcW7qoyNZmttbWRubGZl8V6r9u/k2Je7tIr4I/9wyi9X2x/ZVfej0AjFlRbXZ8scXvBaBjMwDy97/YNA8CICnqW/vAV/ehieclSSDIsDMxyc7ONuZyWMbigv6h/+nwN/TV94zF6f4oD92dk8AUpgro4rqx0lPThXx6ZgaTxaEb/XmI/3HgX5/DMISTwOFzeKKIcNGUcXmJonbz2FwBN51H5/L+UxP/YdiftDjXIlEaPgFqrDGQGqAC5Nc+gKIQARJzQLQD/dE3f3w4EL+8CNWJxbn/LOjfs8Jl4iWTm/g5zi0kjM4S8rMW98TPEqABAUgCKlAAKkAD6AIjYA5sgD1wBh7AFwSCMBAFVgEWSAJpgA+yQT7YCIpACdgBdoNqUAsaQBNoASdABzgNLoDL4Dq4AW6DB2AEjIPnYAa8AfMQBGEhMkSBFCBVSAsygMwhBuQIeUD+UAgUBcVBiRAPEkL50CaoBCqHqqE6qAn6HjoFXYCuQoPQPWgUmoJ+h97DCEyCqbAyrA2bwAzYBfaDw+CVcCK8Gs6DC+HtcBVcDx+D2+EL8HX4NjwCP4dnEYAQERqihhghDMQNCUSikQSEj6xDipFKpB5pQbqQXuQmMoJMI+9QGBQFRUcZoexR3qjlKBZqNWodqhRVjTqCakf1oG6iRlEzqE9oMloJbYC2Q/ugI9GJ6Gx0EboS3YhuQ19C30aPo99gMBgaRgdjg/HGRGGSMWswpZj9mFbMecwgZgwzi8ViFbAGWAdsIJaJFWCLsHuxx7DnsEPYcexbHBGnijPHeeKicTxcAa4SdxR3FjeEm8DN46XwWng7fCCejc/Fl+Eb8F34Afw4fp4gTdAhOBDCCMmEjYQqQgvhEuEh4RWRSFQn2hKDiVziBmIV8TjxCnGU+I4kQ9InuZFiSELSdtJh0nnSPdIrMpmsTXYmR5MF5O3kJvJF8mPyWwmKhLGEjwRbYr1EjUS7xJDEC0m8pJaki+QqyTzJSsmTkgOS01J4KW0pNymm1DqpGqlTUsNSs9IUaTPpQOk06VLpo9JXpSdlsDLaMh4ybJlCmUMyF2XGKAhFg+JGYVE2URoolyjjVAxVh+pDTaaWUL+j9lNnZGVkLWXDZXNka2TPyI7QEJo2zYeWSiujnaDdob2XU5ZzkePIbZNrkRuSm5NfIu8sz5Evlm+Vvy3/XoGu4KGQorBToUPhkSJKUV8xWDFb8YDiJcXpJdQl9ktYS4qXnFhyXwlW0lcKUVqjdEipT2lWWUXZSzlDea/yReVpFZqKs0qySoXKWZUpVYqqoypXtUL1nOozuizdhZ5Kr6L30GfUlNS81YRqdWr9avPqOurL1QvUW9UfaRA0GBoJGhUa3RozmqqaAZr5ms2a97XwWgytJK09Wr1ac9o62hHaW7Q7tCd15HV8dPJ0mnUe6pJ1nXRX69br3tLD6DH0UvT2693Qh/Wt9JP0a/QHDGADawOuwX6DQUO0oa0hz7DecNiIZORilGXUbDRqTDP2Ny4w7jB+YaJpEm2y06TX5JOplWmqaYPpAzMZM1+zArMus9/N9c1Z5jXmtyzIFp4W6y06LV5aGlhyLA9Y3rWiWAVYbbHqtvpobWPNt26xnrLRtImz2WczzKAyghiljCu2aFtX2/W2p23f2VnbCexO2P1mb2SfYn/UfnKpzlLO0oalYw7qDkyHOocRR7pjnONBxxEnNSemU73TE2cNZ7Zzo/OEi55Lsssxlxeupq581zbXOTc7t7Vu590Rdy/3Yvd+DxmP5R7VHo891T0TPZs9Z7ysvNZ4nfdGe/t57/Qe9lH2Yfk0+cz42viu9e3xI/mF+lX7PfHX9+f7dwXAAb4BuwIeLtNaxlvWEQgCfQJ3BT4K0glaHfRjMCY4KLgm+GmIWUh+SG8oJTQ29GjomzDXsLKwB8t1lwuXd4dLhseEN4XPRbhHlEeMRJpEro28HqUYxY3qjMZGh0c3Rs+u8Fixe8V4jFVMUcydlTorc1ZeXaW4KnXVmVjJWGbsyTh0XETc0bgPzEBmPXM23id+X/wMy421h/Wc7cyuYE9xHDjlnIkEh4TyhMlEh8RdiVNJTkmVSdNcN24192Wyd3Jt8lxKYMrhlIXUiNTWNFxaXNopngwvhdeTrpKekz6YYZBRlDGy2m717tUzfD9+YyaUuTKzU0AV/Uz1CXWFm4WjWY5ZNVlvs8OzT+ZI5/By+nL1c7flTuR55n27BrWGtaY7Xy1/Y/7oWpe1deugdfHrutdrrC9cP77Ba8ORjYSNKRt/KjAtKC94vSliU1ehcuGGwrHNXpubiySK+EXDW+y31G5FbeVu7d9msW3vtk/F7OJrJaYllSUfSlml174x+6bqm4XtCdv7y6zLDuzA7ODtuLPTaeeRcunyvPKxXQG72ivoFcUVr3fH7r5aaVlZu4ewR7hnpMq/qnOv5t4dez9UJ1XfrnGtad2ntG/bvrn97P1DB5wPtNQq15bUvj/IPXi3zquuvV67vvIQ5lDWoacN4Q293zK+bWpUbCxp/HiYd3jkSMiRniabpqajSkfLmuFmYfPUsZhjN75z/66zxailrpXWWnIcHBcef/Z93Pd3Tvid6D7JONnyg9YP+9oobcXtUHtu+0xHUsdIZ1Tn4CnfU91d9l1tPxr/ePi02umaM7Jnys4SzhaeXTiXd272fMb56QuJF8a6Y7sfXIy8eKsnuKf/kt+lK5c9L1/sdek9d8XhyumrdldPXWNc67hufb29z6qv7Sern9r6rfvbB2wGOm/Y3ugaXDp4dshp6MJN95uXb/ncun572e3BO8vv3B2OGR65y747eS/13sv7WffnH2x4iH5Y/EjqUeVjpcf1P+v93DpiPXJm1H2070nokwdjrLHnv2T+8mG88Cn5aeWE6kTTpPnk6SnPqRvPVjwbf57xfH666FfpX/e90H3xw2/Ov/XNRM6Mv+S/XPi99JXCq8OvLV93zwbNPn6T9mZ+rvitwtsj7xjvet9HvJ+Yz/6A/VD1Ue9j1ye/Tw8X0hYW/gUDmPP8uaxzGQAAAPFJREFUeJzt101KA0EQBeD3XjpBCIoSPYC3cPQaCno9IQu9h+YauYA/KFk4k37lYhAUFBR6Iko/at1fU4uqbp5dLg+Z8pxW0z7em5IQgaIhEc6e7M5kxo2ULxK1njNtNc5dpIN9lRU/RLZBpZPofJWIUePcBQAiG+BAbC8gwsHOjdqHO0PquaHQ92eT7FZPFqUh2/v5HX4DfUuFK1zhClf4H8IstDp/DJd6Ff2dVle4wt+Gw/am0Qhbk72ZEBu0IzCe7igF8i0xOQ46wFJz6Uu1r4RFYhvnZnfNNh+tV8+GKBT+s4EAHE7TbcVYi9FLPn0F1D1glFsARrAAAAAASUVORK5CYII='
    main()
```

---

**Using Text elements instead of Image elements**

If you don't want to include the custom images, you can change them into simple UNICODE characters and change the `Image` elements into `Text` elements.  The PySimpleGUI element parameters are often the same and in this care they are.  So all that you have to change in the code is the value of the two variables and change the word `Image` to `Text` in the layout.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Demo - Custom Checkboxes done simply

    The Base64 Image encoding feature of PySimpleGUI makes it possible to create beautiful GUIs very simply

    These 2 checkboxes required 3 extra lines of code than a normal checkbox.
    1. Keep track of the current value using the Image Element's Metadata
    2. Changle / Update the image when clicked
    3. The Base64 image definition

    Enable the event on the Image with the checkbox so that you can take action (flip the value)

    Copyright 2022 PySimpleGUI
"""


def main():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Fancy Checkboxes... Simply')],
              [sg.Text(checked, key=('-IMAGE-', 1), metadata=True, enable_events=True), sg.Text(True, enable_events=True, k=('-TEXT-', 1))],
              [sg.Text(unchecked, key=('-IMAGE-', 2), metadata=False, enable_events=True), sg.Text(False, enable_events=True, k=('-TEXT-', 2))],
              [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    window = sg.Window('Custom Checkboxes', layout, font="_ 14")
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        # if a checkbox is clicked, flip the vale and the image
        if event[0] in ('-IMAGE-', '-TEXT-'):
            cbox_key = ('-IMAGE-', event[1])
            text_key = ('-TEXT-', event[1])
            window[cbox_key].metadata = not window[cbox_key].metadata
            window[cbox_key].update(checked if window[cbox_key].metadata else unchecked)
            # Update the string next to the checkbox
            window[text_key].update(window[cbox_key].metadata)

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    checked = '☑'
    unchecked = '☐'
    main()
```

[image]

One advantage of using the Text element addresses your question about size more directly.  You can change the size of the checkbox by changing the font size for the Text element.

I changed it to a size 20 font.  The window has a size of 14 and I left the other checkbox a size 14.  This is the difference:

```py
sg.Text(checked, key=('-IMAGE-', 1), metadata=True, enable_events=True, font='_ 20')
```

[image]

---

`size` parameter footnote....

The `size` parameter you'll find explained in the [API call reference](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#checkbox-element) as part of the docs. All of the elements' parameters are explained in the documentation.
For nearly all elements, it specifies the size of the entire element in **characters** wide and **rows** high.  For the Checkbox, it's only the width that's being used.  If you have another element next to it, then the width will push that other element over if it's longer than the text of the Checkbox.

Comment: OP wanted I want to adjust the size of the checkbox by using its size property.

Comment: I saw that and responded directly to that part, that it's not possible.  The OP ended with the question:
`" How can I change the size?"`
I was then  was urged by an editor, Karl, to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do it with tkinter and Pillow code.

```py
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PySimpleGUI as sg


class Checkbox(sg.Checkbox):

    elements = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        font = kwargs.get('font', sg.DEFAULT_FONT)
        w, h = sg.Text.char_width_in_pixels(font), sg.Text.char_height_in_pixels(font)
        text_color = kwargs.get('text_color', sg.theme_text_color())
        background_color = kwargs.get('background_color', sg.theme_text_color())
        self.images = [self.icon(i, h, text_color, background_color) for i in range(2)]
        size = kwargs.get('size', None)
        size = (size, 1) if isinstance(size, int) else size
        size = (size[0]*w + h + h//3, size[1]*h) if size else (len(args[0])*w + h + h//3, h)
        kwargs['size'] = size
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Checkbox.elements.append(self)

    def initial(window):
        # called after window finalized
        for element in Checkbox.elements:
            element.widget.configure(
                indicatoron=False,
                image=element.images[0],
                selectimage=element.images[1],
                compound=sg.tk.LEFT,
                borderwidth=0,
                offrelief=sg.tk.FLAT,
                selectcolor=sg.theme_background_color(),
            )
        window.refresh()
        window.move_to_center()

    def icon(self, i, h, fg, bg):
        box = (h, h)
        im = Image.new('RGBA', (h+h//3, h), sg.theme_background_color())
        im_check = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(checked if i else unchecked)))
        im_check = im_check.resize(box, resample=Image.LANCZOS)
        im.paste(im_check, box=(0, 0, h, h))
        with BytesIO() as output:
            im.save(output, format="PNG")
            png = output.getvalue()
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=png)

checked = b'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'
unchecked = b'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'

family = "Courier new"

sg.theme("Black")

layout = [
    [sg.Checkbox("Checkbox 1", font=(family, 12), background_color='grey', size=40)],
    [sg.Checkbox("Checkbox 2", font=(family, 16), background_color='grey', size=20)],
    [sg.Checkbox("Checkbox 3", font=(family, 20), background_color='grey', size=10)],
    [sg.HorizontalSeparator()],
    [   Checkbox("Checkbox 4", font=(family, 12), enable_events=True, key="Checkbox 4")],
    [   Checkbox("Checkbox 5", font=(family, 16), enable_events=True, key="Checkbox 5")],
    [   Checkbox("Checkbox 6", font=(family, 20), enable_events=True, key="Checkbox 6")],
]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
Checkbox.initial(window)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[image]

or another one

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('LightGreen')

checked     = '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'
unchecked   = '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'
data = {0:unchecked, 1:checked}

font = ('Times', 100)

layout = [
    [sg.Image(data=unchecked, enable_events=True, metadata=False, key=('CHECK', 0)), sg.Text("English", pad=(20, None), font=font)],
    [sg.Image(data=unchecked, enable_events=True, metadata=False, key=('CHECK', 1)), sg.Text("Chinese", pad=(20, None), font=font)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0]=='CHECK':
        state = not window[event].metadata
        window[event].metadata = state
        window[event].update(data=data[state])

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Never fails to impress me 

Comment: OP wanted I want to adjust the size of the checkbox by using its size property.

Comment: In my first solution, the size of checkbox is decided by the font size. The option `size` is not the size of check box, but the number of characters in a line and the number of lines of text for the checkbox element. Now, the the number of lines of text will be always set to 1 in PySimpleGUI.